# Need Slideshow with Play buttons?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need Slide show like in the below site home page slide show,

http://www.meshnetworks.ca/

Is anyone used before like that slide show?..or any other reference please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have all the slideshow images in seperate divs like this, with only one div displayed at any instance and rest being hidden.

```
    <div id="main_img">
        <img id = "img1" class= "active" src= "images/main_img1.jpg"></img>
        <img id = "img2"  src= "images/main_img2.jpg"></img>
        <img id = "img3"  src= "images/main_img3.jpg"></img>
        <img id = "img4"  src= "images/main_img4.jpg"></img>
    </div>
```

And on click of next or prev button, you set next or prev image as active. fadeout the earlier div and fadeIn the next/prev div like this:

```
function showNextImage(){

current_string = $("#main_img img.active").attr('id');
current = current_string.charAt(3); //get the current image number
current++;
if (current > 4){ //check if current image is the last image display first image
    current = 1;
}
current_string = "img" + current;
$("#main_img img.active").removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000, function(){ //fadeOut existing image
    $("#main_img img").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == current_string){
            $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000) //fadeIn next image
        }
    });
});
}
```

Similarly you can do for previous button.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://pikachoose.com/
Very customisable jquery slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, this site is powed by [Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/),
and the slide show it use is fpss: http://www.frontpageslideshow.net/

Comment: @Ravichandran I'm using TinySlider2, it works fine for me.The demo: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinyslider2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good one http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/