# slideshow within slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

How would I have a default slideshow of thumbnails, like [gallerific](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)! and when the user clicks the thumbnail, have 4-5 slides (say, five different takes of a flower) then be the slideshow.

Or, alternatively, how to have many galleries, and one script that displays the first image of each in a slideshow?

Thanks @thastark.  That takes care of the above request.  Can someone suggest how to take [NIVO Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage) and use it's autoplay (for the 3 big images) and caption?

OR here's my attempt at altering the suggested script in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016294/need-slideshow-with-play-buttons) to get the 3 big images rotating:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="pages">
<div class="navi"></div>
<div class="scrollable">
<div class="items">
       <div class="item"><img id = "img1" class= "active" src= "images/main_img1.jpg"></img></div>
       <div class="item"><img id = "img2"  src= "images/main_img2.jpg"></img></div>
       <div class="item"><img id = "img3"  src= "images/main_img3.jpg"></img></div>
       <div class="item"><img id = "img4"  src= "images/main_img4.jpg"></img></div>
   </div>
</div></div></div></div>

current_string = $("#main img.active").attr('id');
current = current_string.charAt(3); //get the current image number
current++;
if (current > 4){ //check if current image is the last image display first image
    current = 1;
}
current_string = "img" + current;
$("#main img.active).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000, function(){ //fadeOut existing image
    $("#main img").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == current_string){
            $(this).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000) //fadeIn next image
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like slideshows...

Comment: @Eli - A slideshow within a slideshow? I hope you do understand the gravity of that request. That many dreams within dreams erm, I mean slideshows is too unstable!

Comment: So, each nested slideshow must run faster than the slideshow it's nested in...

Comment: With the slightest disturbance, the browser is going to crash.

Comment: somebody calls [Ellen Page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0680983/) here. Only she can handle this or [Leo](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000138/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used jQuery Tools before.  Not as small but decent.

This is similar to what you're talking about (nested slideshow): 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.htm

Here is the description:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html

Comment: Hooray!  How would I make the 3 images... not the thumbnails, but the 3 big images play and loop, and also stop playing on hover.?  I need a caption also.

Comment: Check out the Autoscroll plugin for scrollable (appearance is different but still just a css skin): http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html .. in your case, you have to coordinate stopping / starting the nested slide shows.  Look at circular ref in API to chain slideshow transitions. For the on hover stuff, you'd have to use native jQuery hover event, stop the autoscroll, and restart it.  For captions, the easiest way to do that, is just to include the caption, within each image slide.  The "scrolling slides" are just plain html elements that you can do anything with.

Comment: Sure - it's my username + @gmail.com - give me a holler!

Answer (score 1):

Even I was wanting something like this, you can check my posted ques out.

But temporarily I solved my problem with Nivo slider by using jQuery Dialog boxes i.e. I loaded the slider on a separate dialog box with click event & on "slideShowEnds" I triggered the click event of another slider (which gets loaded in his own dialog box) [width, height , position etc of dialog boxes remain the same]

Answer (score 0):

```
http://gloryplus.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=82&product_id=291

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentImage;
var currentIndex = -1;
var interval;
function showImage(index){
    if(index < $('#bigPic img').length){
        var indexImage = $('#bigPic img')[index]
        if(currentImage){
            if(currentImage != indexImage ){
                $(currentImage).css('z-index',2);
                clearTimeout(myTimer);
                $(currentImage).fadeOut(300, function() {
                    myTimer = setTimeout("showNext()", 3000);
                    $(this).css({'display':'none','z-index':1})
                });
            }
        }
        $(indexImage).css({'display':'block', 'opacity':1});
        currentImage = indexImage;
        currentIndex = index;
        $('#thumbs li').removeClass('active');
        $($('#thumbs li')[index]).addClass('active');
    }
}

function showNext(){
    var len = $('#bigPic img').length;
    var next = currentIndex < (len-1) ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
    showImage(next);
}

var myTimer;

$(document).ready(function() {
    myTimer = setTimeout("showNext()", 3000);
    showNext(); //loads first image
    $('#thumbs li').bind('mouseover',function(e){
        var count = $(this).attr('rel');
        showImage(parseInt(count)-1);
    });
});
```